# ASP.net C# calculate part not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an asp project, the calculate part is not working in one page. I'm try to figure out the issue but I'm not able to get what is going wrong. Please help me with this.
[image: Issue]

[image: no value]
**Amount = ItemQuantity*UnitPrice**

example

**6 = 2*3**

Here is my code behind:

```
private void calculate()
{            
    txtAmount.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtItemqty.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtUnitPrice.Text)).ToString();
} 

protected void txtUnitPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    calculate();
}
```

---

My view controls:

**ItemQuantity**

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemqty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100"  placeholder="Item Quantity"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  onkeyup="calculate();"  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

**UnitPrice**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100"  placeholder="Unit Price"  OnTextChanged="txtUnitPrice_TextChanged" onkeyup="calculate();" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Amount**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  MaxLength="100"  onkeyup="calculate();" AutoPostBack="true" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeydown="return (!((event.keyCode>=65 && event.keyCode <= 95) || event.keyCode >= 106) && event.keyCode!=32);" ReadOnly="true"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: `onkeyup="calculate();"` What is the purpose of this?

Comment: im debug that  cant find  error, no get the value for `txtAmount` no errors, sir

Comment: `onkeyup="calculate();"` remove this from your markup and try it out.

Comment: @SankarRaj sir, im removed , still not working

Comment: can you see the page postbacks after text changed in `txtUnitPrice`

Comment: Define "not working" Is the page posting back? Is the `txtUnitPrice_TextChanged` method being called? Are there conversion errors from text to decimal?

Comment: @SankarRaj sir, actually im try to press two time txtUnitPrice, after debug i can see value

Comment: Please note that the `txtUnitPrice_TextChanged` is executed only after text changed and text box get unfocused i.e)onblur.

Comment: Is `txtAmount` being populated somewhere else?

Comment: @ydoow sir, txtAmount not use

Comment: @SankarRaj sir , do you mean, i need to add onblur? im not clear, can you please make it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the readonly attribute on a control that you would like to programmatically change in web.

Change (txtAmount)--> `ReadOnly="true"` to `Enabled="false"`

Comment: sir, same calculate im used my another page, its working fine

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution, im change my code, and im use `JavaScript`

```
 <script>  function calculate(ctrl1, ctrl2, ctrl3) {

      var c1 = document.getElementById(ctrl1);
      var c2 = document.getElementById(ctrl2);
      var c3 = document.getElementById(ctrl3);

      if (c1 != null && c2 != null & c3 != null) {
          c3.value = Number(c1.value) * Number(c2.value);

      }
      document.forms[0].txteanum.focus();

  }</script>
```

---

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemqty"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100"  placeholder="Item Quantity"  onblur='javascript:calculate("txtItemqty","txtUnitPrice","txtAmount")' ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100"  placeholder="Unit Price"  OnTextChanged="txtUnitPrice_TextChanged" onblur='javascript:calculate("txtItemqty","txtUnitPrice","txtAmount")' ClientIDMode="static"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

---

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  MaxLength="100"  Enabled="false" onblur='javascript:calculate("txtItemqty","txtUnitPrice","txtAmount")' ClientIDMode="static" ></asp:TextBox>
```